# RXJS catchError does not catch network failure errors

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I have a service method which makes an API post request for logging out of the application.

```
public logout(): Observable<APIResponse | ResponseError> {
    return this.http
    .post<APIResponse>(API_ENDPOINT + LOGOUT_URL, '{}', this.httpHeaders)
    .pipe(catchError((error) => {
        return of(this.handleError(error.error));
    }));
}
```

The `catchError` catches all the other valid errors thrown from the server. However, when there's no network connection or when the server is down, it does not work.
What is interesting is the fact that, all these errors are properly caught by my interceptor which does some customised handling for specific responses.

Can anyone tell me why it is working in interceptor but not in my service? I am using the same `catchError` operator in my interceptor too.

Here's the inereceptor

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (req.url.endsWith('/login')) {
        return next.handle(req);
    }
    const body = JSON.parse(<string>req.body);
    const copiedReq = req.clone({ body: body });
    return next.handle(copiedReq)
        .pipe(tap(evt => { }), catchError((err: any) => {
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                const httpError: HttpErrorResponse = err;
                // Custom logic ...
            }
            return of(err);
        }));
}
```

Comment: would be useful if you could also show your interceptor

Comment: @PoulKruijt I've added the interceptor code

Answer (score 1):

If you use the same `catchError` in your interceptor, the behavior you describe is exactly what I would expect. In that case, the error is swallowed by your interceptor.

```
.pipe(catchError((error) => {
    return of(this.handleError(error.error));
}));
```

The `catchError` catches any error on the Observable stream. If an error arrives in your interceptor, it is catched and a new value is emitted on the Observable stream using `of`.

I would recommend to use `throwError` instead of `of` in your interceptor, because then the original error is emitted back on the Observable stream and eventually will arive in your service.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, the problem is that every other error is caught by both my service method and the interceptor, except for the network failure. In case of network failure, the `catchError` is not even getting called.